# LaTeX plugin for vim editor in Linux

Tags: vim

I have installed gvim on my Ubuntu 12.04 operating system.How to install the LaTeX plugin for gvim?I have TeXlive installed.

I used the following link to follow to the instructions:
http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download

I have .vim folder in my home folder but no .vimrc

Comment: The .vimrc file should be located on your $HOME folder, but if it's not, you can create it from scratch and gvim should use it by default.

Comment: Did you check to see whether Ubuntu has this packaged? I imagine it may well do. If so, install it using your package manager so that you automatically get updates etc.

Comment: Can you give some details about what the problem is that you are seeing after you follow the installation instructions. I am unclear what your question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As `gvim` is just `vim` “in gtk-window”, I will use `vim` for convenience.*

---

When you installed `vim` via the packagemanager, it should have gotten its own directory under `/etc` with (at least one) template `vimrc`.

`/etc/vim/vimrc`

`/etc` is usually the place, where configuration-files are stored that apply to the whole system and will be used as fallback, when a user has not defined his own.

Your personalized configuration-file should reside below your homedirectory.
So, usually, it suffices to just have `/home/my_home/vimrc`.

It is always a good idea to copy the configuration-file from `/etc/vim` and change that as needed.
If you so far used vim without a personalized *vimrc*, then it loaded the `/etc/vim/vimrc` and you might notice a different behaviour when you start with an empty *vimrc*.

I would **recommend** to use the hidden directory for vim, in which you can store all vim-related configurations,

i.e. `/home/my_home/.vim/vimrc`

and plugins, such as the latex-suite.

### As for the latex-plugin:

When decompressing the archive, you might **only** get the following directory:

`~/.vim/vim-latex-1.8.23`

But what you need, is to have that directories contents to be directly under `~/.vim`.

For example:

`~/.vim/vim-latex-1.8.23/latextags`
→
`~/.vim/latextags`

So, the plugin (and its documentation) expects a certain order in the directory-tree, without which, the plugin will not be able to function.

---

*I encountered the same problem at first and finally found this solution.
I hope that this can still be of some help.*